# How do I register a web service in a classic asp site

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp-classic

I am working with a classic asp website.
I have created a few ASP.Net pages (ASPX) that we jumped to from an asp page.
The ASP.net pages are using web services to collect and save data. When testing the pages locally I set the references to the web services in my test website (ASP.net).

My question is how to I register the web services in the classic asp website?
Is there anything I need to be aware of that may happen to the classic asp website if it is opened in studio 10 and has references added to it?

this is a live site so having it go down is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: Your question does not really have an answer. While classic ASP is a predecessor to ASP.NET, they have no logical connection to each other even when running side by side on the same site or server. You can install ASP.NET apps or webservices in the same site as a classic ASP site with no ill effect. So, if that doesn't help you might need to significantly expand the detail of your question to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: The no ill effect is what I was looking for. Basically what I did was copy the entire site just in case and then opened in Studio adding the web references as required. Once I saved the solution I looked at the live site and it appears to me that the only thing that changed was the config file. It added each reference in the "appSettings" section as a key. So is that all that would be required if this was completed manually? Sometimes when I am ignorant of how something works I always wonder what MS Studio does behind the scene. Thanks for your input